# Parallelogram symbol

Tags: symbols

I'd tried *Detexify* but no success. Since we have `\square` for quadrilateral and `\triangle` for triangles, I'd like to use a symbol for parallelogram. A kind of slanted square.

Of course, I can do this using `tikz` but I guess that it is too much. I'd need to load a huge package only to draw a single symbol.

Any ideas?

Comment: there's a parallelogram at U+25B1 in unicode, so this would be in the stix or xits fonts.  (those aren't in either detexify or the comprehensive symbols list yet.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks for your comment but I have no idea how to use this glyph. Is it possible to define a `newcommand`?

Comment: i'm certain it's possible to define a `\newcommand{\parallelogram}`, but i haven't ever actually used the stix or xits fonts with (la)tex (even though i helped develop the stix fonts), so this is better answered by someone with real experience.  hence a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks. I found here http://www.stixfonts.org/allGlyphs.html the list of symbols available. As you said, ▰ or  ▱ is what I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

using xelatex (or lualatex):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\[ a ^^^^25b1  b \]


\Large
\[ a ^^^^25b1  b \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: David, as far as I know it is possible to use only some glyphs from that font, isn't? So the math font would be still the cmr. Thanks.

Comment: The stix font have recently been repackaged as a set of fonts for classic (pdf) tex. Using xelatex it's simpler (although not strictly required) to go with the flow and use a matching font for everything.

Comment: `\usepackage{stix}` and use `\parallelogram` is the simplest way to use STIX math fonts, especially for classic pdfTeX.

Answer (score 12):

You don’t need TikZ, you can use PGF (just a little lighter), or if you don’t need rounded line caps/joins (or if you know how to activate them for `\rule`s), a few rules suffice.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,pgf}
\newcommand*{\parallelogramm}{%
  \rlap{\rotatebox{-30}{\rule[.05ex]{.4pt}{.77em}}}%
  \kern.04em%
  \rlap{\kern.36em\raisebox{0.649519052835em}{\rule{.6em}{.4pt}}}%
  \rule{.6em}{.4pt}\kern-.04em%
  \rotatebox{-30}{\rule[.05ex]{.4pt}{.77em}}}
\newcommand*{\Parallelogramm}[1][]{%
  \pgfpicture\pgfsetroundjoin
    \pgftransformxslant{.6}%
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{.60em}{.65em}}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke,#1}%
  \endpgfpicture}
\begin{document}
$\square \triangle$%
\parallelogramm
\Parallelogramm
\Parallelogramm[fill]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Does `pgf` come with basic installation?

Comment: @Sigur I don’t know. PGF is the basic layer of TikZ (or to be precise: TikZ is the front-end layer of PGF). Both together (And more) are bundled under [`pgf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) in TeXLive and MikTeX.

Answer (score 9):

With PSTricks just for fun as usual!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}


\newcommand\parallelogram[1][2]{%
    \psset{unit=#1pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(4,3)
        \pspolygon(0,0)(3,0)(4,3)(1,3)
    \end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
This is a parallelogram \parallelogram. Is it cool? Yes! How about the bigger one \parallelogram[10]? Is it cooler? Yes!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd love to kiss your armpit.

Answer (score 4):

This answer uses `stackengine` and `scalerel` to construct the glyph.  It scales to different math sizes, though the line stroke thickness will be diminished in the process.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\lthk
\setlength\lthk{.1ex}
\def\bline{\rule{2ex}{\lthk}}
\def\slash{\rotatebox{60}{\bline}}
\def\parallelogram{\stackMath\scalerel*{%
  \def\stackalignment{l}{\stackunder[-.5\lthk]{%
  \def\stackalignment{r}\stackon[-.5\lthk]{\slash\rule{.866ex}{0ex}\slash}{\bline}}%
  {\bline}}}{\square}%
}
\begin{document}
$\square \triangle \parallelogram \scriptscriptstyle \square \triangle \parallelogram$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not perfect, but the `stmaryrd` package offers `\fatslash` and `\fatbslash` (as binary operators).

Comment: Thanks, but it is not too fat... lol

Answer (score 3):

The `stix` package gives you not only `\parallelogram` and `\parallelogramblack`, but also `\fltns`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

$\parallelogram \parallelogramblack \fltns$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output (sorry for upload from Paint)]

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling hacky, or are working on an online platform based on KaTeX, this is a mediocre, but perhaps passable ASCII-inspired solution:

```
 \underline{/\overline{ \vphantom{/} \hphantom{a}}\,}\!\overline{/}}
```

[image]

Hopefully you don't need to use this, though :)